# Nginx for multiple Docker Container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, load-balancing, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to implement different ports for different docker containers . If request to 8080 port ,it should go nginx container and so on.

my docker-compose file

```
version: "3"

services:
  ngnix:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf/:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    command: [nginx-debug, "-g", "daemon off;"]
  apache:
    image: httpd
    command: bash -c "httpd -D FOREGROUND"
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
```

and my nginx.conf file below  :

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;


    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_redirect     off;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 8081;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8081;
            proxy_redirect     off;
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not work  .Where is my mistake I spent my all time ?

Comment: In Docker 127.0.0.1 is always “this container”.  Docker documentation like [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes the general networking environment you get in a Docker Compose setup and how to make calls from one container to another.

Comment: Cant I do it by using nginx?

Comment: Your nginx isn’t listening on port 8081, so `http://127.0.0.1:8081` reaching port 8081 in this container goes nowhere.

Comment: You are not really utilising Docker networks, instead your requests are being proxied in the way that your apps need to be exposed on the host. Instead of doing this, you should put nginx and applications in same Docker network, that way they will be accessible within and not outside container. Take a look at https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy.

Comment: I want , if i write docker-compose up ,it works. But jwilder/nginx-proxy you have to do manuallly